# Modify JsonResponse in Api

Tags: python, html, json, django, api

I am trying to get my objects from a database using an **API.**

**I get this response:**

```
{
"bicykels": [
    {
        "name": "Ohhh",
        "lat": "74",
        "lng": "53"
    },
    {
        "name": "Ohhh",
        "lat": "-111",
        "lng": "-5"
    },
    {
        "name": "Ohhh",
        "lat": "-64",
        "lng": "-31"
    },
  ]
```

}

**I would like to get something like this *(without the text "bicykels")*:**

```
[
    {
        "name": "Ohhh",
        "lat": "74",
        "lng": "53"
    },
    {
        "name": "Ohhh",
        "lat": "-111",
        "lng": "-5"
    },
    {
        "name": "Ohhh",
        "lat": "-64",
        "lng": "-31"
    },
  ]
```

**I've tried almost everything but I don't know how to do it. I'll be so glad if you can help me.
Here is the code:**

```
def customer_get_bicykel(request):

    uzivatel = request.user.id

    bicykels = BicykelSerializer(
        Bicykel.objects.filter(),
        many = True,
        context = {"request": request}
    ).data

    return JsonResponse({"bicykels": bicykels})
```

**And code of the Serializers:**

```
class BicykelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Bicykel
        fields = ("name", "lat", "lng")
```

Comment: Seems like you removed the wrong tag. What language are you actually working with? What is shown is definitely not javascript

Comment: It's python. I've changed the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your function to return the following:

```
return JsonResponse(bicykels, safe=False)
```

Comment: It has helped. Thank you so much. :)